# Uncaught type error when binding Events to Kendo dropdownlist

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I tried to bind a event for select action on Kendo dropdownList. I have put in the 
quotes for the event handles because without the extra quotes the event handler was appearing as it is on the javascript code and gave errors.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("yearDropDown")
.DataTextField("Text")
.DataValueField("Value")
.BindTo(new List<DropDownListItem>() { new DropDownListItem() { Text = "2015", Value = "2015" }, new DropDownListItem() { Text = "2016", Value = "2016" }, new DropDownListItem() { Text = "2017", Value = "2017" }, new DropDownListItem() { Text = "2018", Value = "2018" } })
.Events(e => {
    e.Select("\"drpDwnForecastYearSelect\"");
})
.Value(userInput.year)
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width : 8em" })
)
```

And I have written the handler in javascript as well. But when I click on a option in the dropdown i get a error like this in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: r[n].call is not a function
    at init.trigger (kendo.all.js:124)
    at init._change (kendo.all.js:32793)
    at Object.<anonymous> (kendo.all.js:32802)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at init._click (kendo.all.js:32801)
    at init.d (jquery.min.js:2)
    at init.trigger (kendo.all.js:124)
    at init._click (kendo.all.js:28060)
    at HTMLLIElement.d (jquery.min.js:2)
```

The problem I face is very similar to [this support ticket](https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-grid-server-side-pagination-throws-uncaught-typeerror-r-n-call-is-not-a-function-upon-navigating-to-next-page) but there is no resolution there and I can't post there without purchasing premium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not introduce extra double quotes** in the select event handler specification

Change

```
e.Select("\"drpDwnForecastYearSelect\"");
```

back to

```
e.Select("drpDwnForecastYearSelect");
```

If you have not defined a **global** javascript function `drpDwnForecastYearSelect` then the browser debug console will show

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: drpDwnForecastYearSelect is not defined
at . . .
```

#### Correct

Define the select handler as a global function.

```
<script>
    function drpDwnForecastYearSelect(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
</script>
```

The global scope is available to the scope of the JavaScript rendered by the DropDownList helper (*the handler is invoked from within a kendo.syncReady() closure*).  The script block containing the handler function can appear before or after the helper.

#### Wrong

Defining the function within jQuery document ready, such as the following

```
    $(function () {
        // Welcome to jQuery document ready 
        function drpDwnForecastYearSelect(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    })
```

will not work.  The scope of a function defined in a `$( document ).ready()` closure is not available to the scope of the `kendo.syncReady()` closure code rendered by the DropDownList helper.

Comment: Amazing explanation. Thanks